# Perform an action per element with a common class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to fade in a share link when clicked on a share icon, but the problem am having is that they are many of them, it is like a post and am using a common class to fade in the links, when i click on one icon all the share link fades in, is there any way to fade in the link per each post, am trying to keep my code dry.

```
<div class="first-post">
<li class="fire-share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
    <ul class="shareo">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>  

<div class="second-post">
<li class="fire-share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
    <ul class="shareo">
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>

$('.fire-share').click(function(){
    $('.shareo').fadeToggle()
})
```

I have tried using .each()  but it still throws up the same problem, if i use different classes or id's it works fine but a post of many numbers, its not dry

```
$('.fire-share').click(function(){
      $('.shareo').each(function(i,obj){
      $(this).fadeToggle()
   })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use this context to tell the clicked element
2. Use find to search for the specific element that is within the parent element

   ```js
   $('.fire-share').click(function(){
       $(this).find('.shareo').fadeToggle()
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="first-post">
   <li class="fire-share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
       <ul class="shareo">
           <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   </div>  

   <div class="second-post">
   <li class="fire-share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
       <ul class="shareo">
           <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   </div>
   ```